# Uploadify on MAC

Tags: uploadify

i noticed that mac and the flash-plugin gets in conflict when doing multiple uploads.
There's no problem when it's only 3 or 5 files, but when the amount of files is higher then uploadify just stops uploading. The plugin kinda crashes.

Strangely on windows there is no single problem with multiple uploading.

I upgraded Flash, both on mac and windows. I checked the sessions-id's, i checked this forum, the forum at uploadify.
But can't find where to search for...

Can somebody give me some clues about what to do.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

I am also using uploadify v3.2.1. I came here looking into why it isn't working for some mac users, but stumbled upon your question and seeing it has no feedback on it, I will try to point you onto something that could be a solution....

Are you using PHP? If yes; Did you verify that the total post size is not going above what is allowed for php?

The php.ini file has the setting for post size limit, if the amount of images in one request goes beyond that which is set in the php.ini, it may be causing this, as you only get it when uploading more than 3-5 files (which can amount to a size over that limit) and not when uploading less than that... try raising the post size limit and then retrying the upload file-set that fails right now...